# How to use OptionsMenu (from react-native-options-menu) in react-native-router-flux's header?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I wanted to use `OptionsMenu` menu from `react-native-options-menu` with `react-native-router-flux`'s header component. Here's my approach

MenuOptions.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import OptionsMenu from "react-native-options-menu";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

const MenuOptions = () => {
    const myIcon = (<Icon name="rocket" size={30} color="#900" />);
    return(
        <OptionsMenu
            customButton={myIcon}
            destructiveIndex={1}
            options={["Edit", "Delete", "Cancel"]}
        />
    );
}

export default MenuOptions;
```

Router.js:

```
import ...
import MenuOptions from "./components/MenuOptions";
const RouterComponent = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>

                <Scene key="auth">
                    <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} title="Please login" initial />
                </Scene>

                <Scene key="main">
                    <Scene 
                    key="..." 
                    component=... 
                    title="..." 
                    rightTitle="More"
                    onRight={()=> {
                        return <MenuOptions />
                    }}
                    initial
                    />
                    <Scene> ... </Scene>
                </Scene>

            </Scene>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default RouterComponent;
```

When i click on More, menu options are not loaded. What's wrong with my approach? Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

use `renderRightButton = {<OptionsMenu ../>}` instead of `onRight`,
renderRightButton waits a component, while onRight waits a function.